# running a java program in linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run a java program in linux environment. The program is structured as follows.

src (directory)

- main (directory)

  --  test.java
- common (package)

  --  a.java

  -- b.java

Test.java is my main program.

I used the following command to run the program from the src directory level.

javac -cp "../../lib/netcdf.jar:/common/*.java" main/test.java

I am getting errors related to package common not found and all the classes under it are not found.

Can you please help me solve this.

Thanks

Comment: You should just be able to `javac` the main class. The compiler will draw in the resources in needs based on the imports in the file.

Comment: Try cding into the directory then running the command.

Comment: what are you importing in your source file? classes and packages that you import are somewhere? are they linked in your classpath? how?

Comment: @thermz : How do I link the netcdf jar and the common package to the classpath? when I compile like javac main/test.java, it throws errors realted to classes in netcdf jar files. so, when I link them to the classpath like, javac -cp "../../lib/netcdf.jar" main/test.java, I get errors related to package common not found.

Comment: I think that Kevin answer is the way to go in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had it compiled and running by using the following command

javac -classpath '.:../../lib/*' main/test.java

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't expand the glob (`*`), unless it's the lone, last piece of a path (in which case it expands to all the jar files).  It's been a while, but I believe you should be able to just leave the `*.java` off entirely (`-cp "../../lib/netcdf.jar:common"`).  And it appears you were using `/common`, which would make it look for a folder named `common` in the root of your system.

Comment: I ran the follwing commnand per ur suggestion: javac -cp "../../lib/netcdf.jar:common" main/test.jar. But doesnt seem to work though. I am still getting the errors

Comment: @ShenoyTinny Oh, "common" is really a jar file, "common.jar"? make the `common` in the cp `common.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems here.

Firstly, javac *[compiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)* your code in class files (.class). It doesn't run the code, but converts the source code into a form that can be run.

When compiling code, all the .java files should be structured according to their package. So you can't arbitrarily decide to put some java files in one folder and some in another folder. For example, if a java file specifies "package com.mycompany" and your src directory is specified as src then the java file must be located in "/src/com/mycompany".

In your code, when you need to reference other code (usually external libraries) that have already been compiled into .class files, you can specify the *classpath* (which is why it is called as such). Note, I'll repeat this for clarity, this is not for .java files, but for .class files. Sometimes lots of .class files are packaged together into a single archive file, called a java archive, or '[jar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29)'.

Also note, on unix systems that "/common" is an absolute [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). If you want a relative path, you should specify "./common".

Additionally, the classpath separator is ";" not ":".

So in summary, if none of your java files specify an explicit package, simply put all your .java files in the same directory (I suggest ./src). Then run `javac -sourcepath ./src *.java` or simply `javac *.java` from the src directory.

There's more on managing source files and class files [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

Answer (score -3):

Open terminal

Type `java`

Display some packages

You install this packages

Now installed java packages

Now type `java`

Type `javac`

Type `appletviewer`

You make new a directory=> `md arivu`

`cd arivu`

`gedit ex.java`

Now you save

Return to terminal

Compile: `javac ex.java`

Run: `java ex`

Graphical code:

- javac ex.java
- appletviewer ex.java

Comment: This answer doesn't look completely relevant to the original question.